# recv() in FTP client

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp

I am trying to create FTP client in C++ using BSD sockets, I can create socket, get welcome message, send user name, but I can not move on. Here is my dubug output:

```
Socket created
Connected

220 server - welcome message

Msg: USER anonymous

Received bytes: 75
331 Anonymous login ok, send your complete email address as your password
```

Then I am stucked at this point for 5 minutes, server terminates connection and I finally get response:

```
Received bytes: 61
331 Anonymous login ok, send your complete email address as your password
421 Login timeout (300 seconds): closing control connection
our password

Received bytes: 0
Msg: PASS password

Received bytes: 0
Msg: SYST

Received bytes: 0
Msg: PASV

Received bytes: 0
Msg: LIST

Received bytes: 0
Msg: QUIT

Received bytes: 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Here is my function for sending and receiving messages. I put there socket and message for FTP server (for example `USER anonymous\r\n`)

```
void communication(int sock, const char *msg) {
string response;
char server_reply[2000];
printf("Msg: %s\n", msg);
send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
//Receive a reply from the server
int rval;
do
{
    rval = (int) recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0);
    printf("Received bytes: %d\n", rval);
    if (rval <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else {
        response.append(server_reply);
        puts(response.c_str());
    }
}
while (true);
```

My program looks like this:

```
//Receive a welcome message from the server
if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0) {
    puts("recv failed");
}

puts(server_reply);
memset(&server_reply[0], 0, sizeof(server_reply));

const char *usernameMsg = "USER anonymous\r\n";`
communication(sock, usernameMsg);`
const char *passwdMsg = "PASS email@email.com\r\n";`
communication(sock, passwdMsg);
communication(sock, "SYST\r\n");
communication(sock, "PASV\r\n");
communication(sock, "LIST\r\n");
communication(sock, "QUIT\r\n");
```

Could you tell me, what's wrong please? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried sending an email address when the server is asking? I guess the rest are follow up errors. You should avoid this: `421 Login timeout (300 seconds): closing control connection`

Comment: @Hayt yes, I have tried. My program looks like this:    
    `const char *usernameMsg = "USER anonymous\r\n";`
    `communication(sock, usernameMsg);`
    `const char *passwdMsg = "PASS email@email.com\r\n";`
    `communication(sock, passwdMsg);`
    `communication(sock, "SYST\r\n");`
    `communication(sock, "PASV\r\n");`
    `communication(sock, "LIST\r\n");`
    `communication(sock, "QUIT\r\n");`

Comment: @TomášHrnčiar Please update your question. It's nearly unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yes, I realised it right after posting, it is updated now.

Comment: If your socket blocking or non-blocking? (your code is wrong in any case)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have never heard about it so I looked into man pages and tried `MSG_WAITALL` flag, but it was same like before. Please could you explain me what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously expect the `recv` to return 0, when there's no more response from the server.

But that's wrong for blocking mode. In the blocking mode `recv` will always wait until there are some data. Note that the socket is a generic interface to a connection. The connection is a just a stream of data. There's no end-of-the-message mark. So the socket cannot magically find out that a complete response was received from the FTP server. It's up to you. It's you task to call `recv` only until you receive the CRLF sequence, which signals the end-of-the-response in the FTP protocol. And it's actually even more complicated as the FTP response can be multi-line. Read the FTP specification.

---

Your primary problem now, is that your first call to the `communication()` function never finishes.

Once you read the `331` response to the `USER` command, you start waiting for the next message (second round [or even later, in the rare case the `331` response is longer than the 2000 characters] of the `while` loop in the first call of the `communication()` function). But the server is actually waiting for your next command, which you never send. So the server eventually gives up, sends you the `421` response and disconnects you.